# How to correctly bend an object

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, bezier-curves

Very beginner question, I'm attempting to have barbed wire twisting while moving in multiple directions behind a subject.
[image: photo]
I purchased this barbed wire 3d model and I've figured out how to animate it how I'd like to to look but I just can't manage to bend it.
https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/architectural/other/barb-wire-chrome

Not sure if im better off using simple deform or curve modifier. I'm pretty lost on where to start but I don't think what I'm attempting is very difficult just having trouble with it.

https://youtu.be/DnOELJXghOQ

Finally, what would be the best workflow to achieve my final image?
Multiple barbs exported as indvidual ones and layer them in premiere or could this be done in Blender
[image: blender screenshot]
[image: blender screenshot2]

Comment: don't know much about animation or rigging, but for a similar project a friend of mine suggested using bendy bones, whatever that is. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Let say you've made your barbed wire with an *Array* modifier + *Curve* modifier. If you just want them to bend, you just need to subdivide your curve and move its handles, it will bend the barbed wire. If you want to bend + animate, here is a solution:

- Select your curve, enter in *Edit* mode and <kbd>W</kbd> > *Subdivide* it enough.
- Select each handle and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object*.
- This has created empties that you can use to move the handle, thus bend your barbed wire as you want.
- To make it more convenient and be able to reset the empties to their 0 position you can create an armature, and inside this armature create as many bones as you have empties.
- Now switch your armature in *Pose* mode and select the first bone.
- Select the corresponding empty, re-click on the bone, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone*. Do the same for each empty.
- Now the bones control the empties that control the handles, and you can come back to the basic curve position going in the armature *Pose* mode and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to reset.

This solution will allow you to have a very flexible barbed wire, but if you don't need complicated movements you can use the *Mesh Deform* modifier or *Bendy Bones*, as Mathmaniage said.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how the curve tool works, I don't have a curve to modify just yet.  This screen grab might give more context https://youtu.be/DnOELJXghOQ

Comment: oh yes because you need to create a curve all along the barbed wire length, then choose it in the modifier. You will easily find some tutorial on this matter. Also, you may need to put your subsurf modifier on the bottom of the modifiers stack

Comment: I see a lot on how to use curves when modeling, but I'm having trouble seeing how it fits with an object that already exists.They often use the curve tool first then model around that. What's the best way to apply a curve to the barbed structure I have?

Comment: it will allow you to easily bend your object, either it is an arrayed object or not. And it will also allow you to animate if you associate the handles to empties, as I show in my explanation.

Comment: Yep i gotcha and I understand you there but do you see what I'm saying as far as me having trouble applying the tool to an object that's already made? In tutorials I can follow along and it makes sense if I was modeling an object from scratch but in this case the object is already there and the curve can't just be applied in the modifiers tab. I appreciate the help, like I said I'm very new to blender so these things trip me up pretty easy.

Comment: yes the object is already made but you can give it a Curve modifier without any problem, don't apply it though, just keep it in the modifiers and choose the curve as the its Object. You just need to learn how the Curve modifier works with some tutorials (for example you need to set the right direction and to put its origin at its beginning point).